# Functions, variables and nested selects

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say you have a nested SQL in SQL Server in which you need to use the result of a function evaluated on the outer select:

```
SELECT FUN(...) as Result,
       (SELECT count(*)
        FROM Table
        WHERE ... < Result
FROM Table
WHERE Condition
```

That won't work because of an 'unknown column Result' in the inner query.

How can I rewrite it?

Comment: is this a real life example please? At first glance there are far better ways of doing such a query.

Comment: I'm sure about that. I'm completely new to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about nesting things differently:

```
SELECT
  r.Result,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE ... < r.Result) AS SomeCount
FROM
  (
    SELECT FUN(...) AS Result, ... FROM Table WHERE Condition
  ) AS r
```

Comment: @Roberto: Good to hear. Be sure to have an index on the field that you compare `r.result` to, so the `COUNT(*)` returns quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider something like this instead if you're on SQL Server 2005

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM
  (
  SELECT FUN(...) AS Result, ... FROM Table WHERE Condition
  ) foo
  CROSS APPLY
  (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS SomeCount FROM Table WHERE ... < foo.Result
  )
```

Note: the query you posted can often be solved using window/ranking functions in SQL Server 2005+